# Selecting rows from a dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe:

```
>>> d = {'ID' : ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DFG', 'DFG', 'DFG', 'EGF', '2BD', '2BD'], 'Val': ['High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'High'], 
... 'Num': [22,2,16,10,50,3,2,34,2], 'Val2':['Low', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High']}
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
    ID  Num   Val  Val2
0  ABC   22  High   Low
1  ABC    2   Low  High
2  ABC   16  High   Low
3  DFG   10  High  High
4  DFG   50  High  High
5  DFG    3   Low  High
6  EGF    2   Low  High
7  2BD   34   Low  High
8  2BD    2  High  High
```

Is there a way to apply conditions to rows that have same value in a column, and then apply some conditions to check values in other columns?

I want an output like this:

```
ID | Val | Num | Val2

ABC | High | 22 | Low
DFG | High | 50 | High
EGF | Low  | 2  | High
2BD | High  | 2  | High
```

i.e., where for the same IDs in the first column, it checks the Val column, gives high precedence to 'High' value than 'Low' or 'Mod' and then from among the rows for that ID with 'High' in the Val column select the row with higher value in the 'Num' column.

I'm doing it as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID' : ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DFG', 'DFG', 'DFG', 'EGF', '2BD', '2BD'], 'Val': ['High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'Low', 'Low', 'Low', 'High'], 'Num': [22,2,16,10,50,3,2,34,2], 'Val2':['Low', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High', 'High']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df

x = df.ID.unique().tolist()
f_df=pd.DataFrame()
idlist=[]
vallist=[]
numlist=[]

for i in x:
    idlist.append(i)
    new_df = df.loc[df['ID'] == i]
    h_df = new_df.loc[df['Val'] == 'High']
    if h_df.empty:
        m_df = new_df.loc[df['Val'] == 'Mod']
        if m_df.empty:
            l_df = new_df.loc[df['Val'] == 'Low']
            vallist.append('Low')
            if len(l_df) > 1:
                m = l_df['Num'].max()
                numlist.append(m)
            else:
                m = l_df['Num'].max()
                numlist.append(m)
        else:
            vallist.append('Mod')
            if len(m_df) > 1:
                m = m_df['Num'].max()
                numlist.append(m)
            else:
                m = m_df['Num'].max()
                numlist.append(m)

    else:
        vallist.append('High')
        if len(h_df) > 1:
            m = h_df['Num'].max()
            numlist.append(m)
        else:
            m = h_df['Num'].max()
            numlist.append(m)

f_df['ID'] = idlist
f_df['Val'] = vallist
f_df['Num'] = numlist

print f_df
```

Is there a better way to do this? Also, how do I also get corresponding value of `Val2`in the output? Coz I actually have a dataframe with 12 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited to add

The really *pandonic* way to do this is with *categories*:

```
>>> df['Val'] = df.Val.astype('category').cat.set_categories(['High','Mod','Low'], ordered=True)
>>> df['Val2'] = df.Val2.astype('category').cat.set_categories(['High','Mod','Low'], ordered=True)
>>> df
    ID  Num   Val  Val2
0  ABC   22  High   Low
1  ABC    2   Low  High
2  ABC   16  High   Low
3  DFG   10  High  High
4  DFG   50  High  High
5  DFG    3   Low  High
6  EGF    2   Low  High
7  2BD   34   Low  High
8  2BD    2  High  High
>>> df.dtypes
ID        object
Num        int64
Val     category
Val2    category
dtype: object
```

So now sorting works how we want!

```
>>> (df.sort_values(['Val','Num'], ascending=[True, False])
...    .groupby('ID')
...    .nth(0))
     Num   Val  Val2
ID
2BD    2  High  High
ABC   22  High   Low
DFG   50  High  High
EGF    2   Low  High
```

#### Original Answer

Yeah, I think you wan't to use the built-in sorting and `groupby`, so first, create columns that map your "High", "Mod", and "Low" values to *numbers* so we can work with them sanely and easily:

```
>>> df['valmap'] = df.Val.map({'High':0, 'Mod':1, 'Low':2})
>>> df['val2map'] = df.Val2.map({'High':0, 'Mod':1, 'Low':2})
>>> df
    ID  Num   Val  Val2  valmap  val2map
0  ABC   22  High   Low       0        2
1  ABC    2   Low  High       2        0
2  ABC   16  High   Low       0        2
3  DFG   10  High  High       0        0
4  DFG   50  High  High       0        0
5  DFG    3   Low  High       2        0
6  EGF    2   Low  High       2        0
7  2BD   34   Low  High       2        0
8  2BD    2  High  High       0        0
```

And then I think you just want:

```
>>> df.sort_values(['valmap','Num'], ascending=[True, False]).groupby('ID').nth(0)
     Num   Val  Val2  val2map  valmap
ID
2BD    2  High  High        0       0
ABC   22  High   Low        2       0
DFG   50  High  High        0       0
EGF    2   Low  High        0       2
```

You can, of course, always select the columns you want specifically:

```
>>> (df.sort_values(['valmap','Num'], ascending=[True, False])
...    .groupby('ID')['Num','Val', 'Val2']
...    .nth(0))

     Num   Val  Val2
ID
2BD    2  High  High
ABC   22  High   Low
DFG   50  High  High
EGF    2   Low  High
```

So, if you think about your requirements:

"where for the same IDs in the first column, " => use `groupby('ID')`

"gives high precedence to 'High' value than 'Low' or 'Mod' and then from among the rows for that ID with 'High' in the Val column select the row with higher value in the 'Num' column." => Sort by Val, then by Num (descending), then take the highest.

Comment: Wow! Perfect! This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Xavier I edited to use categories, a very handy feature of pandas.